# How to delete dbf rows containing an alpha value or an entire dbf column

Tags: python, delete-row, dbf

I would like to delete some rows & columns on my dfb that contain specific data.

Let's assume that the structure of the dfb looks like the image bellow and that I want to remove the rows with 'knapford' as 'Prov' and the 'Reg' column.

[image]

When I try following this script:

```py
table = dbf.Table(wonderland.dbf).open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)
with table as tab:
    print (table)
    for record in dbf.Process(tab):
        dbf.delete(record[0])
```

I get this error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-4-d8feabfc9819>", line 4, in <module>
    dbf.delete(record[0])

  File "C:\Users\fassi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 8349, in delete
    if not template and record._meta.status == CLOSED:

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

I had this other suggestion in mind, but I wonder if it will really delete all the fields of the row, just some specific ones or all the records!

```py
table = dbf.Table(wonderland.dbf).open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)
with table as tab:
    dbf.delete_fields(table, Reg)
    for record in dbf.Process(tab):
        if record[0].strip()=='Knapford': #since we've delete the Reg, Prov is becoming record[0]?
            dbf.delete(record)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this should work:

```
from simpledbf import Dbf5

dbf = Dbf5('file.dbf')
data = dbf.to_dataframe()

for row in range(len(data)):
    Reg= data.loc[row,'Reg']
    Prov = data.loc[row,'Prov']
    if Reg =='knapford' or Prov =='knapford':
        data.drop(index=row, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

This other script work very well:

```
import dbf
with table as tab:
    for record in dbf.Process(tab):
        if record[1].strip()=='Knapford':
            #print (record)
            dbf.delete(record)
table.pack()
```

Comment: Dear @Misieq ,
I retried this code for the same dbf, and it did work just for the rows in the dataframe (didn't delete the rows of the dbf). I don't know what I'm missing since it worked the 1st time ^^"

Comment: becuase in this line:
`data = dbf.to_dataframe()`
we are copying 'dbf' into 'data' variable and from now on we are working on 'data'

Comment: I undertand that, but why did it work the 1st time? Bizarre isn't it ?!